# nopage () method implementation

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

Any one know about how virtual address is translated to physical address in no page method.
with reference to Device Drivers book the nopage method is given as ,

```
struct page *simple_vma_nopage(struct vm_area_struct *vma,
                unsigned long address, int *type)
{
    struct page *pageptr;
    unsigned long offset = vma->vm_pgoff << PAGE_SHIFT;
    unsigned long physaddr = address - vma->vm_start + offset;
    unsigned long pageframe = physaddr >> PAGE_SHIFT;

    if (!pfn_valid(pageframe))
        return NOPAGE_SIGBUS;
    pageptr = pfn_to_page(pageframe);
    get_page(pageptr);
    if (type)
        *type = VM_FAULT_MINOR;
    return pageptr;
}
```

page_shift is the number of bits used to reperesent offset for Virtual and physical memory address.
But what is the offset variable ?
How a physical address is calculated from arithmetic operations on virtual address variables like address and vm_start ?

Comment: Please let me know if u got this clearly.Iam stucked in this topic for pat 5 days. As we know subtraction of two pointer pointing elements in same array will give the number of elements between them.Like that whether Subtraction of two virtual memory addresses will give us the number of pages in between these two virtual addresses(address & vm_start). I just stated the above point but don't know whether it helps to solve this problem..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel the documentation of vm_pgoff is not very clear. 
This is the offset of the first page of the memory region in RAM.
So if our RAM begins at 0x00000000, and our memory region begins
at 0x0000A000, then vm_pgoff = 10. If you consider/ revisit the mmap 
system call then you can see that the "offset" which we pass is the offset
of the starting byte in the file from which "length" bytes will be mapped
on to the memory region. This offset can be converted to address by left 
shifting it to PAGE_SHIFT value which is 12 (i.e. 4KB per page size)

Now, irrespective of whether the cr3 register is used in linear address to 
physical address translation or not, when we say that "address - vm_start" 
then this gives the size of portion between the addresses.
example:
    vm_start = 0xc0080000
    address  = 0xc0090000

```
address - vm_start = 0x00010000
physaddr    = (address - vma->vm_start) + offset;
            = 0x00010000 + (10 << PAGE_SHIFT)
            = offset_to_page_that_fault + start_addr_of_memoryRegion_in_RAM  
            = 0x00010000 + 0x0000A000
            = 0x0001A000
```

Now since this is the physical address therefore we need to convert to page frame 
number by right shifting by PAGE_SHIFT value i.e 0x0001A000 >> 12 = 0x1A = 26 (decimal)
Therefore the 26th page-frame must be loaded with the data from the file which is being mapped.
Hence data is retrieved from the disk by using the inode's struct address_sapce 
which contains the information of the location of page on the disk (swap space).
Once the data is brought in we return the struct page which represents this data in the 
page_frame for which this page fault occurred. We return this to the user.

This is my understanding of the latest but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

"simple_region_start" is the offset from the starting of
physical memory out of which our sub-region needs to be mapped

Example:
    off = start of the physical memory (page aligned)= 0xd000 8000
    simple_region_start = 0x1000
    therefore the physical address of the start of the sub region 
    we want to map is = 0xd000 8000 + 0x1000
              = 0xd000 9000

now virtual size is the portion that needs to be mapped from the 
physical memory available. This must be defined properly by the user.

simple_region_size = physical address pointing to last of the 
portion that we need to map.

So if we wanted 8KBs to be mapped from the physical memory available
then following is how the calculation goes

```
simple_region_size = physical address just beyond the last of our portion
simple_region_size = 0xd000 9000 + 0x2000 (for the 8KBs)    
simple_region_size = 0xd000 B000
```

So our 8KBs of portion will range from physical addresses [0xd000 B000 to 0xd000 9000]
    Hence physical size i.e. psize = 0x2000

We perform the sanity check i.e
If the size of our portion of physical memory is smaller 
than what the user tries to map using the full length 
virtual address range of this memory region, then we 
raise an exception. i.e say for ex. vsize = 0x3000

Otherwise we use the API "remap_pfn_range" to map the 
portion of the physical memory passing in the the 
physical address and not the page frame number as 
was done previously since this is the IO memory.
I feel it should have been the API "io_remap_page_range"
here the aforementioned.

So it will map the portion of physical memory starting 
from the physical address 0xd000 9000 on the the user
linear address starting from vma->vm_start of vsize.

N.B As before I have yet to test this out !

Answer (score 0):

No, the statement in the book is correct, because
As aforementioned, "physical" is just the address
Of starting of your region/portion that you want
To map out of the physical memory which starts 
From "off" physical address till the "simple_region_size"
The "simple_region_size" value is decided by the user.
Similarly "simple_region_start" is decided by the user.

```
simple_region_start >= off
```

So the maximum physical memory that user can map
Is decided by: psize = simple_region_size - off
I.e from start of physical memory till end
of the portion.

But actually how much will be mapped with this memory 
region is given by "vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start" and is
represented by vsize. Hence the need existed to perform 
the sanity check since User can get more than what it
intended.

```
Kind regards,
Sanjeev Ranot
```

Comment: I u wish , Please share your email id.so that i can ask if i had any  doubts in future .Its difficult to find persons with knowledge on DDrivers.Mine is balaganesh.v@hcl.com.